# Prove $\max(T(x,y),T(w,z))=T(\max(x,y),\max(w,z)).$

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $T : [0, 1]\times [0, 1] \rightarrow [0, 1]$. A $t$-norm is a function $T$ with properties:

1. $ T (x, 1) = x$
2. If $y\leq z$ then $T(x,y)\leq T(x,z)$
3. $T (x, y) = T (y, x) $
4. $T (x, T (y, z)) = T (T (x, y), z) $

Prove $$\max(T(x,y),T(w,z))=T(\max(x,y),\max(w,z)).$$

I have spent much time to prove it, but I don't know how to start the proof.

Any hint to prove it?

Comment: Are you sure that the equality holds? Pick $y = z = 1, x,w < 1$. Then $RHS = T(1,1) = 1$ and $LHS = max(T(x,1), T(w,1)) = max(x,w) < 1$.

Comment: So, I can conclude with your counter example, that equality is not holds. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since disproving the equation is also acceptable, I will give an alternative approach(from my comment). Note that multiplication in $[0,1]$ fulfills the $4$ requirements. Thus, by setting $T(x,y) = x \cdot y~$ the equality we want to check becomes $$ \max(x\cdot y, w\cdot z) = \max(x,y) \cdot \max(w,z)$$ and we can find many counterexamples.